# How to make Rss News Reader application in android ....?

Tags: java, android, xml, json, rss

i have a sample code for parsing data from XML , In XML parsing SAX,DOC,and XML Pull parser 
which is the best XML parser ,what is json parser...? and how to parse news feeds through json parser.please answer with any examples

```
   public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {
   private String   

  finalUrl="http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/worldservice/globalnews/rss.xml";
  private HandleXML obj;
  private TextView title,link,description;
  private LinearLayout mWeatherInfosLayout;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   finalUrl = intent.getStringExtra("url");
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
   mWeatherInfosLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.weather_infos1);
   fetch();

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
}
  public void fetch(){
   obj = new HandleXML(finalUrl);
  obj.fetchXML();
  mWeatherInfosLayout.removeAllViews();
  while(obj.parsingComplete)
  {     

      if(obj.gotit)
      {

        final LinearLayout forecastInfoLayout = (LinearLayout) 
                getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.feedlist, null);

        final TextView tvWeather1 = (TextView)   
  forecastInfoLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview_forecast_info1);

        final TextView tvWeather2 = (TextView) 
  forecastInfoLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview_forecast_info2);

        final TextView tvWeather3 = (TextView) 
  forecastInfoLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview_forecast_info3);

        final TextView tvWeather4 = (TextView) 
    forecastInfoLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview_forecast_info4);

        tvWeather1.setText(obj.getTitle());
        tvWeather4.setText(obj.getPubDate());
        tvWeather2.setText(obj.getLink());
        String string = obj.getDescription();
        String[] parts = string.split("<");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        tvWeather3.setText(part1);
        mWeatherInfosLayout.addView(forecastInfoLayout);
        obj.setgotit();
        }
     }

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HandleXML Class accordingly.

```
public class HandleXML {

   private String title = "title";
   private String link = "link";
   private String description = "description";

   private String urlString = null;
   private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
   public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
   public HandleXML(String url){
      this.urlString = url;
   }
    public String getTitle(){
     return title;
   }
   public String getLink(){
    return link;
  }
  public String getDescription(){
    return description;
 }
   public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;
     try {
      event = myParser.getEventType();
       while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String name=myParser.getName();
          switch (event){
          case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
          break;
        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
           text = myParser.getText();
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
           if(name.equals("title")){
              title = text;
           }
           else if(name.equals("link")){    
              link = text;
           }
           else if(name.equals("description")){
              description = text;
           }
           else{
           }
           break;
     }       
     event = myParser.next(); 
   }
   parsingComplete = false;
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
   public void fetchXML(){
     Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
 @Override
 public void run() {
  try {
     URL url = new URL(urlString);
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
     conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     conn.setDoInput(true);
     // Starts the query
     conn.connect();
     InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
     xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
     myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
     myparser.setInput(stream, null);
     parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
     stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }
    });
    thread.start(); 
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much i use this code its working ...

Comment: your welcome. please tick the answer and also vote up my answer thanks.